# C++ Project hangs at Compiling

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction, freeze

My boss has a C++ project that just began hanging today when he hits either the "Build Solution", "Rebuild Solution", or "Compile" buttons. The Build window says compiling and hangs there. He has tried reverting back to the project state from a week ago using Subversion but no dice.

We also have a solution that uses the same source code, but builds in VS2005, and that builds fine. Any ideas? We'd really love to not have to re-install VS but if it comes down to it we might have to.

*EDIT* Also, it is a C++ project, but the files in the project are all C.

Comment: Does it hang on his computer only, or does it hang on any computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case. If you have any add-ons installed in MS VS 2008 then disable all of them to make sure that they do not cause that.

Comment: I started the project in SafeMode to disable all add-ons, built the project, and it worked. Closed and re-opened VS2008 the normal way and it builds fine now.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me, but after further investigation it turns out our copy of Bullseye was ancient and is not meant to work with MSVC90.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that when you're reverting you are reverting ALL files (i.e. the solution file, make, etc.), not just the source code.

Comment: We deleted the folder and did an update on it's parent. It's all been restored to a vanilla state, if you will.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have VS2008 SP1 installed?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa718359

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. When VS2008 is loaded, it tries to update IntelliSense. If you ask VS2008 to build solution before IntelliSense update is completed, the build process (or clean solution process) may hang at any point. In my case, the solution is to wait "Updating IntelliSense...(1701)" (it shows on the status bar)  to be completed.

Comment: Couple points, one this seems unlikely to be the issue. Two, if they have not solved this problem by now (4 years on) they are probably out of business.

Comment: But, @zchrykng, Stack Exchange web sites are not some help forum to solve a specific user's problem, but aim to be Q&As that are helpful to any future visitor as well. So I feel the time argument is moot.